# Jenkins pipeline can't build docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to build a docker image from a Dockerfile using a declarative pipeline in Jenkins. I've successfully added the 'jenkins' user to the docker group, and can run 'docker run hello-world' as the jenkins user manually. However, when I attempt to build through the pipeline, I can't even run 'docker run hello-world':

From the pipeline:

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ whoami
jenkins
[workspace] Running shell script
+ groups jenkins
jenkins : jenkins docker
[workspace] Running shell script
+ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker 
daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post 
http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/containers/create: dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

Manually sshing into Jenkins and switching to the 'jenkins' user:

```
*********@auto-jenkins-01:~$ sudo su - jenkins -s/bin/bash
jenkins@auto-jenkins-01:~$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
(amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://cloud.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/
```

Some other useful information: Jenkins is running from a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to give jenkins user group privileges to docker unix socket by editing /etc/default/docker and adding:

```
DOCKER_OPTS=' -G jenkins'
```